# How does redefining function's toString method work?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, overriding

I am trying to solve a code challenge where I came across a challenge to chain functions and most of the solutions i could find online were using `function.toString` and override `toString` method of function like in the following code to chain add function.

```
function sum(n) {
  var v = function(x) {
    return sum(n + x);
  };

  v.toString = function() {
    return n;
  };

  return v;
}
```

What does `toString` do here to replace function call method? and how does `toString` work here without a bracket like `toString()`

Comment: What you are doing here is creating a property in `v` called `toString`. So when you do `v.toString`, you will call this function. If this function is not available, engine will look up the chain using prototype and call the function, if found. Also, adding parenthesis after a function name will call it. Not using them essentially uses references and can be used for assignment

Comment: how does adding a parenthesis call the function? like how does the engine know to call a property without reference like v.property?  or v.()

Comment: Name of a function is a reference pointer to it. When engine sees parenthesis after a property, it will try to execute it. If its a function, it will be executed. If its not, it will throw error. But it needs a property name

Comment: So we are calling the function anonymously when we use paranthesis?

Comment: Can this method be used to add anonymously callable functions to any variable?

Answer (score -1):

```js
var result

function v(n,x){
result = (n+x).toString()
}

// This function return sum of  two parameters as a result in string type. toString() functions allows you to parse anything into String.
```

Comment: The motive of the question is to figure out how chaining works in functions?

Comment: sorry then, my mistake. anyway v.toStirng() is not a variable unless you assign it to anything then assign function return n

Comment: Yes but apparently v.toString works to override function methods and I am trying to figure out how that works